# How to secure react native Bluetooth connection with password?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I’d love to make react native Bluetooth app which will connect to the raspberry pi zero w.

So I am about to use this library called react-native-ble-plx.

However, I’d love to secure the connection with password. Is it possible to do so?

The problem is that react-native-ble-plx documentation does not mention any password parameter when connecting to the ble device.

Your help would be highly appreciated as there are scarce resources regarding this.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Does Bluetooth bonding fit for you? With that either device generates a 6 digit random number (new each time) that the device displays and the user inputs that number on the other device.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks promising! And does it have to generate new password each time? The thing is that the raspberry will not feature any display whatsoever. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes it must be a new one each time, otherwise the protocol is not secure. Without a display or input capabilities, Bluetooth pairing will not give you man-in-the-middle-protection. If you want a static password and a secure method you need to use a PAKE (this is something you need to implement yourself since the Bluetooth standard does not include this).